# ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied error connection to remote oracle server

Tags: php, linux, oracle

I have two web application and Oracle servers.

Web application server has the following details:

1. Linux server (LAMP)
2. oci8
3. PHP 7.4

Oracle Database server has the following details:

1. Oracle 19C

I am trying to connect Web Application Server to Oracle Database Remote Server. When I try to connect with remote Oracle server as a result following error shows:

> ERROR is ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied.

---

*Note: While this remote Oracle Database server is connecting successfully from Windows server (WAMP).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592508/oracle-tns-permission-denied

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle TNS Permission Denied \*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592508/oracle-tns-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first running of the web application? Can you connect to the database from the system running your web application using sqlplus?

Answer (score 0):

In my case was the firewall. I enabled one rule that forbade the connection with the server. I just disabled the rule and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. Though i wasn't using LAMP. I had a manually configured apache-php setup. I had to run the command in the Linux server to allow apache to make network connections - apparently, SELinux prevents this by default.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

after seeing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26349596/9914081 which can be of help too.